# Office 365 SMTP Relay

Tags: office365

When we send emails through a connector(not a particular email of office365) of SMTP relay of office 365,

1. Does emails send will be shown in sent items?
2. Can we setup an email on office 365 which can receive the email status(opened, clicked, delivered, bounced, etc..) of all the emails that we sent through a connector of SMTP relay of office 365?
3. How we can track emails we send emails through a connector(not a particular email of Office 365) of SMTP relay of office 365? Any PHP code or office 365 API available for this.

Regards,
Vipul

Answer (score 0):

1. When you send emails through an Office 365 Connector, it is relayed through Office 365.
   Exchange is simply told to accept emails from the connection and relay them onward to the target, so no, you cannot in Exchange at least see it in the traditional way of a "Sent Items" folder.
2. Yes, there are a few ways to do this, the most simple and likely best pratice way would be to create a shared mailbox, then make sure that the applications sending through the connection uses the email of the shared mailbox as their "from" / "sender" address. That way, anything that bounce or gets replied to will end up in this shared mailbox.
3. You can track it through the Exchange control panel or through powershell. I would recommend that you start by checking out [this article from codetwo](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/message-tracking-office-365/)